# Having trouble with Downheap Algorithm via array implementation

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am currently trying to sort my array of keys using the Down-heap algorithm. However, when I display my newly sorted array, new numbers appear and the order doesn't seem right. I cannot tell if something is wrong with my algorithm or if I'm not using the proper conditions for this sorting algorithm.

My job is to sort an array of 20 keys.

**The Code:**

```
/* Downheap sorting algorithm */
for(i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    j = i + 1;

    /* If parent is less than both children */
    if(key[j] < key[2*j] && key[j] < key[(2*j)+1])
    {
        /* Check which child is smallest */
        if(key[2*j] < key[(2*j)+1])
        {
            /* Parent is assigned smallest node */
            swap(&key[j],&key[2*j]);
        }
        else{swap(&key[j],&key[(2*j)+1]);}
    }

    /* If parent is less than left child */
    else if(key[j] < key[2*j])
    {
        swap(&key[j],&key[2*j]);
    }

    /* If parent is less than right child */
    else if(key[j] < key[(2*j)+1])
    {
        swap(&key[j],&key[(2*j)+1]);
    }
}
```

**The Swap Function:**

```
void swap(int *parent, int *child)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *child;
    *child = *parent;
    *parent = temp; 
}
```

Array of keys **before** sorting:

```
54,90,137,260,185,65,208,139,114,176,186,77,137,139,178,57,203,110,80,127
```

Array of keys **after** sorting once:

```
54,137,185,260,114,77,208,178,110,176,186,65,137,139,139,64,203,90,84,127
```

64 was not there before. Where is 57? 80 has disappeared and where did 84 come from?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You might want to check the termination condition of your loop: how many array elements are defined, ond how big does `(2*j)+1`get?

Comment: It turns out that my file (I failed to mention I was reading these numbers from a file, displayed as a 20x10 matrix) had extra spaces at the end of each line. I fixed that problem and the algorithm works just fine.

Comment: For a test, make the array twice as large + 1 and initialise with minimum and maximum values for the key before reading in (even seeing you accepted an answer addressing the same problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of 20 numbers they will usually be key[0]..key[19], and with a heap you will need to consider the possibility that one or more of the children of a heap element do not exist because their array positions would be off the edge of the array. With heap numbers 0..19 then the children of element i would be at 2i+1 and 2i+2, so 0 has children 1 and 2, 1 has children 3 and 4... 8 has children 17 and 18, but 9 has only one child at 19 and 10 has no children at all.

Are you expecting Downheap to do all of the work of sorting? Normally, as explained at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort, Downheap is part but not all of Heapsort.

Comment: Woops. Seems like I missed that class! I'll check out the link and try to pull it together. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By "DownHeap"  i am asuming you mean Min-Heap

Algo for min heap :

`public void insert(Comparable x)
{
    if(size == heap.length - 1) doubleSize();`

```
//Insert a new item to the end of the array
int pos = ++size;

//Percolate up
for(; pos > 1 && x.compareTo(heap[pos/2]) < 0; pos = pos/2 )
    heap[pos] = heap[pos/2];

heap[pos] = x;
```

}'

Check This Link To understand min heap[min heap](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Binary%20Heaps/heaps.html)